# Remove namespace declaration in child nodes

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I have an XML with namespace declared at root node and also at child nodes. I want the namespace declaration(xmlns:pi="urn:com.employee/enroll) to be removed at child nodes. Any suggestions?

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<pi:Extract_Employees xmlns:pi="urn:com.employee/enroll">
    <pi:Header xmlns:pi="urn:com.employee/enroll">
        <pi:Version>17</pi:Version>
        <pi:Company_Name>Payroll Company</pi:Company_Name>
    </pi:Header>
    <pi:Employee xmlns:pi="urn:com.employee/enroll">
        <pi:FirstName>Test</pi:FirstName>
        <pi:LastName>Test</pi:LastName>
    </pi:Employee>
    <pi:Employee xmlns:pi="urn:com.employee/enroll">
        <pi:FirstName>Test1</pi:FirstName>
        <pi:LastName>Test1</pi:LastName>
    </pi:Employee>
    <pi:Employee xmlns:pi="urn:com.employee/enroll">
        <pi:FirstName>Test2</pi:FirstName>
        <pi:LastName>Test2</pi:LastName>
    </pi:Employee>
</pi:Extract_Employees>
```

Desired Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<pi:Extract_Employees xmlns:pi="urn:com.employee/enroll">
    <pi:Header>
        <pi:Version>17</pi:Version>
        <pi:Company_Name>Payroll Company</pi:Company_Name>
    </pi:Header>
    <pi:Employee>
        <pi:FirstName>Test</pi:FirstName>
        <pi:LastName>Test</pi:LastName>
    </pi:Employee>
    <pi:Employee>
        <pi:FirstName>Test1</pi:FirstName>
        <pi:LastName>Test1</pi:LastName>
    </pi:Employee>
    <pi:Employee>
        <pi:FirstName>Test2</pi:FirstName>
        <pi:LastName>Test2</pi:LastName>
    </pi:Employee>
</pi:Extract_Employees>
```

Comment: Try doing the identity transform. If your processor is smart enough, it will discard the redundant namespace declarations.

Comment: Thanks Michael for your suggestion, it worked, this small piece of code helped.